# Using AutoMapper with Interface

Tags: .net-core, automapper

I am using AutoMapper for mapping couple of my Server models to UI models. I am working on a dotnet core solution really stuck in the following situation

Server Model :

```
public interface IUserValue : IValue
{
    string EmailId { get; set; }
}

public class UserValue : IUserValue
{
    public string EmailId { get; set; }
}

public interface IUserProperty : IProperty
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}

public class UserProperty : IUserProperty 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public interface IUser 
{
    IUserValue Value { get; set; }
    IUserProperty Property { get; set; }
}

public class User 
{
    public IUserValue Value { get; set; }
    public IUserProperty Property { get; set; }
}
```

And UI model something like

```
public class UserUIModel 
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have successfully mapped the UI object from server object using the following code

```
CreateMap<User, UserUIModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => 
            dest.Email, opts => 
                opts.MapFrom(src => 
                    src.Value.EmailId))
        .ForMember(dest => 
            dest.Name, opts => 
                opts.MapFrom(src => 
                    src.Property.Name));
```

Can anyone suggest me how I can achieve the reverse mapping that is from UserUIModel to User object ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `ReverseMap()` function at the end of your CreateMap logic, like this:

```
CreateMap<User, UserUIModel>()
        .ForMember(dest => 
            dest.Email, opts => 
                opts.MapFrom(src => 
                    src.Value.EmailId))
        .ForMember(dest => 
            dest.Name, opts => 
                opts.MapFrom(src => 
                    src.Property.Name))
        .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: After doing this, I am running with this error > Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
UserUIModel -> User followed by > 
Type Map configuration:
UserUIModel -> User

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is still searching how this thing get fixed, this is how, I figured it out.

AutoMapper does not create object that are of Interface type, in my case, if we can see *User* class, there are properties, but all of type some kind of Interfaces. So I had to put some manual or default behavior of these interface type references. That is >

```
public class User 
{
   public IUserValue Value { get; set; } = new UserValue();
   public IUserProperty Property { get; set; } = new UserProperty();
}
```

And it works fine for me.